# How to run a function through multiple sublists in R?

Tags: r, nested-lists, sapply

I have a complex nested list named AllVotes that you can find here (in .rds) :

https://github.com/JMcrocs/MEPVote/blob/master/FinalVotes.rds

I am trying to collect all the `mepid`, a named number stored in the sublists `AllVotes[[x]]$votes$'+'$groups`. Thanks to a previous question here I am able to do that for one list (the [[1]] list) but I would like to do it for all the list of my nest list from [[1]] to [[2336]].

```
#For the list [[1]]
Result = c(unlist( sapply ( names ( AllVotes[[1]]$votes$'+'$groups ), 
                   function(x) unlist( AllVotes[[1]]$votes$'+'$groups[[x]] ) ) ),
unlist( sapply ( names ( AllVotes[[1]]$votes$'-'$groups ), 
                   function(x) unlist( AllVotes[[1]]$votes$'-'$groups[[x]] ) )),
unlist( sapply ( names ( AllVotes[[1]]$votes$'0'$groups ), 
                   function(x) unlist( AllVotes[[1]]$votes$'0'$groups[[x]] ) )))
```

How can I do that? Thank you in advance !

PS : Sorry if the question is not perfect I am two weeks new to programming (and Overflow).

Comment: Could you provide the result of `dput(AllVotes)` or similar for reproducibility?

Comment: @niko Sadmu, the dput(AllVotes) is too big to be provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code to:

```
res <- lapply(AllVotes, function(x){
  unlist(lapply(c('+', '-', '0'), function(y){
    x$votes[[y]]$groups
  }))
})
```

which gives the same output as **@Duck**'s answer.

```
all.equal(res, List, check.attributes = F)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a loop and saving results in a list as next:

```
#Load
AllVotes <- readRDS('FinalVotes.rds')
#Loop
#Empty list
List <- list()
#For
for(i in 1:length(AllVotes))
{
  List[[i]] <- c(unlist( sapply ( names ( AllVotes[[i]]$votes$'+'$groups ), 
                                  function(x) unlist( AllVotes[[i]]$votes$'+'$groups[[x]] ) ) ),
                 unlist( sapply ( names ( AllVotes[[i]]$votes$'-'$groups ), 
                                  function(x) unlist( AllVotes[[i]]$votes$'-'$groups[[x]] ) )),
                 unlist( sapply ( names ( AllVotes[[i]]$votes$'0'$groups ), 
                                  function(x) unlist( AllVotes[[i]]$votes$'0'$groups[[x]] ) )))
}
```

You will end up with `List` having `2336` elements. You can access the elements by using  for example `List[[15]]` and so on. Then you can process the list according to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a strategy using `lapply()`. Convert your code to an anonymous function, replacing `AllVotes[[1]]` with the argument of your function, say `list`.

```
AllVotes <- readRDS('FinalVotes.rds')
out_list <- lapply(AllVotes, function(list) {
  c(unlist(sapply(names(list$votes$'+'$groups),
      function(x) unlist(list$votes$'+'$groups[[x]]))),        
      unlist(sapply(names(list$votes$'-'$groups), 
      function(x) unlist(list$votes$'-'$groups[[x]]))),
      unlist(sapply(names(list$votes$'0'$groups),
      function(x) unlist( list$votes$'0'$groups[[x]]))))
   })
```

I benchmarked my answer against Duck's `for` loop answer using the `rbenchmark` package to run each version 100 times. The two arguments to `benchmark()` are functions that I defined as wrappers around the two approaches so the output would be easier to interpret.

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(lapply_test(), loop_test())
           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1 lapply_test()          100  102.08    1.043    100.91     0.25  
2   loop_test()          100   97.86    1.000     96.87     0.15
```

It looks like the two approaches are nearly equivalent on my machine, taking about 1 second for each iteration. The loop version is a tiny bit faster, but difference is so small that different machines may run the lapply version faster. For very large files, one of these may emerge as a clear winner. Also, with very large the files, the lapply version is easily parallelized.